# Are python imports guaranteed to be in sequence order? Is relying on this a good idea?

Tags: python, import

If I have the following Python code:

```
import module1
import module2
```

- Does Python guarantee that `module1` is loaded before `module2`, and that they are not, for example, loaded in parallel? This works in CPython, but I would like the code to be portable to other flavours too, including ones that allow multithreading. Searching the Python specification does not turn up anything.
- Is relying on the import order a good idea, even if it is guaranteed? The initialization code in `module1` must run before that in `module2`. I did not think the alternative, `module1.init()` then `module2.init()` was very pythonic.

Comment: Yes, the imports will happen in order. No, relying on that is not a good idea. You actually should avoid doing any real work at module import time, particularly modifying some sort of global state.

Comment: Be aware that if these imports are, themselves, listed in a module, that either or both of `module1` and `module2` may have **already** been imported before your module runs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, the import order is guaranteed.
2. No, it's not a good idea. It's very easy to break this by importing another file before importing `module1` that imports `module2`. If you want `module1` to run before `module2`, It's much better to explicitly import `module1` at the top of `module2`.

Comment: which is further hinted at by unofficial guidelines such as alphabetical ordering or system/library/user ordering. Your answer is spot on.

Comment: @keyser good point. I want to do `F5` in my favorite editor to order imports and not have that break anything. The only exception I can think of are imports from `__future__` which are required to be at the very top.

Comment: @LukasGraf Doesn't that work well with both alphabetical and system ordering? :) Good point nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks. I guess some refactoring is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

The imports will occur in the order they're encountered in code execution.  However, that may not be the same as the order they're listed in any particular file, since other modules may import modules as well.  For instance, if you have:

```
import foo
import bar
import baz
```

and `foo.py` has `import baz` at the top, then `baz` will be imported before `bar` (assuming none of these modules has already been imported).

If module2 requires module1 to be loaded, the simplest thing is to have module2 import module1.  This will not "re-do" the import if module1 was already imported (it will just use the already-imported module), so it has negligible performance impact.